# SQL query for calculating mtd, ytd values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with columns `ID`, `Title`, `Date`, `Amount`.

I need to get MTD, YTD amount values against each transaction based on `Title`, `Date`.

Is there anyone who had done this before?

Comment: Please edit you question first, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select t.title, t.Date, 
  Sum(y.Amount) YTD,
  Sum(m.Amount) MTD
From table t
   left join table y
      on y.Title = t.Title
         and datediff(year, y.Date, t.Date) = 0 
         and y.Date <= t.Date
  left join table m
      on m.Title = t.Title
         and datediff(month, m.Date, t.Date) = 0 
         and m.Date <= t.Date
         and m.Date <> y.Date
Group by t.title, t.Date
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful

Comment: This is not a correct answer as each join multiplies the number of rows used in the SUM calculation. Let's say that we have a small table with just 2 rows. Each row has the same title, but a different date within the same month and year. Then for the first date there will be only 1 row used for the SUM, because t rows * y rows * m rows = 1 * 1 * 1 = 1, but for the second date there will be 4 rows - 1 * 2 * 2. So if the Amount in the rows were 2 and 3 respectively, you will get MTD = 10 and YTD = 10, where it really should be 5 and 5.

Comment: @Peter,  I think the fact that the OP's questions asks about Month "to Date" and year "to Date"  values explains the choice of using <= comparison operators. In your example, for the first date, there IS only one transaction "to date", and for the second date, there are two.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, I understand the use of <=. I think you missed my point. Look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/969960/2/1). The YTD and MTD amounts in the second row should be 5 and 5 respectively, not 10 and 10.

Comment: @Peter, Yes, you're correct, I think they need to be left joins, and the second joined table needs to exclude row where the date is the same s the first join date. that seems to address your sample data, I'm working on this to determine if it works for other scenarios as well. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesBretana, Unfortunately that still does not provide correct results. It returns null for the MTD value of very first transaction. It will also return incorrect values for MTD of every transaction outside of very first month in each year. If you want to stick to sorting this out in joins, you would need to left join the m table on `y.ID = m.ID and datediff(month, m.Date, y.Date) = 0`. You could also use `CROSS APPLY` for the m table and use `CASE` statement there.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/969960/26)

Comment: @Peter,Yes you're correct again... I think another approach would be to use subqueries based on a constructed table... but it's not as elegant.. I am working on this.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted solution is incorrect. Let's say we have a following table:

```
ID   Title   Date        Amount
---  ------  ----------  ------
  1  Cust A  2020-01-01    2.00
  2  Cust A  2020-01-05    3.00
  3  Cust A  2020-02-01    5.00
```

The accepted answer would give us these results:

```
Title   Date        YTD    MTD
------  ----------  -----  -----
Cust A  2021-01-01   2.00   2.00
Cust A  2021-01-05  10.00  10.00
Cust A  2021-02-01  10.00  15.00
```

This is due to the fact that each join multiplies the number of records by the number of matching records. This can be easily seen when the aggregation is removed:

```
Select t.title, t.Date, y.Date, m.Date,
  y.Amount,
  m.Amount
From [table] t
   join [table] y
      on y.Title = t.Title
         and datediff(year, y.Date, t.Date) = 0 
         and y.Date <= t.Date
   join [table] m
      on m.Title = t.Title
         and datediff(month, m.Date, t.Date) = 0 
         and m.Date <= t.Date
Order by t.title, t.Date, y.Date, m.Date
```

Results:

```
Title   t.Date      y.Date      m.Date      y.Amount    m.Amount
-----   ----------  ----------  ----------  --------    --------
Cust A  2021-01-01  2021-01-01  2021-01-01         2           2
Cust A  2021-01-05  2021-01-01  2021-01-01         2           2
Cust A  2021-01-05  2021-01-01  2021-01-05         2           3
Cust A  2021-01-05  2021-01-05  2021-01-01         3           2
Cust A  2021-01-05  2021-01-05  2021-01-05         3           3
Cust A  2021-02-01  2021-01-01  2021-02-01         2           5
Cust A  2021-02-01  2021-01-05  2021-02-01         3           5
Cust A  2021-02-01  2021-02-01  2021-02-01         5           5
```

Here is a modified select that produces correct results:

```
Select a.title, a.Date, 
  Sum(Case When datediff(year, b.Date, a.Date) = 0 Then b.Amount Else 0 End) YTD,
  Sum(Case When datediff(month, b.Date, a.Date) = 0 Then b.Amount Else 0 End) MTD
From [table] a
   join [table] b
      on a.Title = b.Title
         and b.Date <= a.Date
Group by a.title, a.Date
```

Results:

```
Title   Date        YTD    MTD
------  ----------  -----  -----
Cust A  2021-01-01   2.00   2.00
Cust A  2021-01-05   5.00   5.00
Cust A  2021-02-01  10.00   5.00
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/969960/17) with all the current answers plus new solutions.

Comment: Hi Peter, your final solution is a life-saver and a game-changer. I wrote big CTEs for Daily, Monthly and Yearly and then combined all to get the same....but this is simply elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,
       Title,
       Date,
       Amount,
       MTD  = SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Title, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)),
       YTD  = SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Title, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, [Date]), 0))
FROM   [a_table]
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful

Comment: This seems to get the full totals rather than running totals.  I mean, YTD has the same value (total for year) for all records in the year, rather than the total of only the records from previous months.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution by using **Cross Apply**:

[see this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/969960/159)

```
CREATE TABLE [table] (
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Title nvarchar(20),
  Date date,
  Amount money
)

INSERT INTO [table] (Title, Date, Amount)
VALUES ('Cust A', '2021-01-01', 2.00),
       ('Cust A', '2021-01-05', 3.00),
       ('Cust A', '2021-02-05', 4.00),
       ('Cust A', '2021-02-06', 5.00),
       ('Cust B', '2021-01-01', 20.00),
       ('Cust B', '2021-01-05', 30.00),
       ('Cust B', '2021-02-05', 40.00),
       ('Cust B', '2021-02-06', 50.00);
       
SELECT t1.title
      ,t1.Date
      ,t1.Amount
      ,t2.Amount_YTD
      ,t3.Amount_MTD
FROM [table] t1
     CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount_YTD
    FROM [table] t2
    WHERE t2.Date <= t1.Date
          AND t1.Title = t2.Title
          AND datediff(year, t1.Date, t2.Date) = 0 
) t2
     CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount_MTD
    FROM [table] t3
    WHERE t3.Date <= t1.Date
          AND t1.Title = t3.Title
          AND datediff(month, t1.Date, t3.Date) = 0 
) t3
```